# how to open a folder within Powershell

Tags: powershell

How to open a folder in PowerShell?
I am **not** talking on how to start PowerShell in a specific folder.

What I mean is that in the command line of powershell i would like
to open a folder e.g: " open document"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to open an explorer window from powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320509/is-it-possible-to-open-an-explorer-window-from-powershell)

Answer (score 104):

Use the `Invoke-Item` cmdlet, or its alias: ii.

```
PS> ii c:\windows # open the windows directory in windows explorer
PS> ii c:\book.xls # open book.xls in Excel
PS> ii . # open the current directory in windows explorer
```

Answer (score 38):

For Powershell and cmd compatible way (and I think the most common way):

```
start .
start c:\
```

Comment: dunno if that should be the most common - invoke-item / ii is much more powershelly :)

Comment: I like this, works similar to `open .` for macOS `zsh` shell.

Answer (score 10):

To open the current folder within the powershell type:

PS>> explorer.exe $(pwd)

Answer (score 9):

Use `Invoke-Item`, alias `ii`:

```
ii d:\temp\
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use the explorer.exe to open the folder:

```
explorer.exe c:\temp\
explorer.exe <YourFolderPathHere>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add as well to the mix:

```
PS C:\> ii -path c:\directory\directory\directory
```

If your file name has two words with a separation consider single quotation marks:

```
PS C:\> ii -path 'c:\directory\directory\directory directory\'
```

The following work [note -path is optional]

```
   1. ii or invoke-item
   2. explorer.exe
   3. start
```

Answer (score 3):

Putting a dot after `explorer.exe` will open the current directory:

```
explorer.exe .
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize the question is old but folks finding this via google may find this useful even now:

I created a cmd script with:

```
@REM Open directory
@REM Version 1.0
@echo off
if [%1]==[] (powershell ii .
    ) Else (
        powershell ii %1
        cd %1
    )
```

This will also open a document such as a text file or a MS Word document, as well as opening a folder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you want, but I have two possible solutions:

```
explorer .\Documents
```

or

```
cd .\Documents
```

Answer (score 0):

As 'open .' in mac will open the current directory, 'start .' in window PowerShell will do the same.

Answer (score -1):

another variant

```
 hh c:\

 hh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471106

 hh $env:windir\help\WindowsPowerShellHelp.chm
```