# How do I open a folder(on my desktop) from Powershell on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal

On an online tutorial on webservers, the guy(on a MAC) opened a folder which was on his desktop by typing 
**>> cd folder-2

> > open .**
> >     how do I  do the same(equivalent to double clicking on the folder) using Powershell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to open a Windows Explorer window from PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320509/is-it-possible-to-open-a-windows-explorer-window-from-powershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cmd powershell type:

```
explorer.exe $path
```

where $path is the name of folder with full path

Comment: Doesn't have to be the full path.. Relative paths work as well. `explorer .` opens the current working directory.

Comment: Yes, that is true. You can give a relative or absolute path to the folder you want to open..

Answer (score 5):

There are three ways that immediately come to mind:

1. `start $folder`, where $folder is the path of the folder to open - it can be either a fully qualified pathname (e.g., `C:\Users\Me\Documents\Letters`) or a relative pathname (e.g., `Letters`)
2. `Invoke-Item $folder`, where $folder is the path of the folder to open, as above. By default, `Invoke-Item` has an alias, `ii`.
3. `explorer $folder`, where $folder is the path of the folder to open, as above.

Method 1 also works in `cmd.exe`. Both method 1 and method 2 can also take a file name instead of a folder pathname, and will cause the default action for the item to occur - for example, `Invoke-Item notes.txt` or `start notes.txt` will open notes.txt in notepad (or your system default text editor).